# Rails multitable id incrementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application using Postgres - I need to have some tables that have the same data in essence. So I need to have a unique key that increments for all my tables, so there is virtually a pk constraint over all the table's ids. 
Now, the question is - how do I do it? can I write a migration that defines the id of all the tables to increment for each insert to any of those tables? or must I do it on the database level?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do something which you should not do. If you need to constrain columns in multiple tables then there _must_ be an association between them, a way to create foreign keys between them. In which case you should keep the incrementing column in one table (possibly a new table) and foreign keys referencing it from the other tables.

Comment: Totally agree with Wizard of Ogz. I don't really understand the need here. Single Table Inheritence or a `has_one` relation should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a link between two tables, you shouldn't make them have the same primary key. This is not a good use of a database.

You should instead give one of these tables a foreign key to the other one, and use this relation to identify the linked rows between the two tables.

In Rails, it's called a "has_one" relation, and it's very handy : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Comment: I really don't think I agree, when you have two tables that you only union/minus/intercept for querying - in order to select between them, there is no point of having a foreign key.

Comment: Why do you need to have exactly the two same tables, with the same columns (if you union them, I guess they have the same columns) and the same data in it ?

Comment: Think of it as an STI, where you don't waste space with irrelevant data - and MTI, is not good for my case either - because each table is by itself, and it will be very inefficient to query multiple tables in comparison to one.

Comment: Then why not use only one table with STI ? I don't understand your "waste of space" argument, you have exactly the same space occupied by your two tables than if you had one with all rows. You can keep your querying efficient if you index the `type` column of your STI.

Comment: Because I don't have the same data - I union the tables and still query which results to show using the data in the table - the selected columns are different from the where conditions - an STI of that table will have many null columns.

Comment: Ok, no STI. But still, I think synchronising your ids will get you a bigger headache than querying two tables with a foreign key.